# How to use PostgreSQL triggers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL triggers in my rails app. So I tried using this migration where execution of triggers is supposedly easy:

```
-- class AddTriggersToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    table :products
    execute %q{
        create trigger trig1 before insert on products for each row
        begin 
        price = price + 5
        end;
        }
  end

  def self.down
    execute 'DROP TRIGGER trig1'
  end
end
```

But this didn't change anything. I don't know where to write the procedure or function if I am going to use one here ...

Answer (score 10):

"Creating a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html)" consists of **two steps** in PostgreSQL:

1.) Create a [**trigger function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunctsion.html) - with special return value `trigger`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_update_prod_price()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.price := NEW.price + 5;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Multiple triggers can use the same trigger function.

2.) Create a [**trigger**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) calling an existing trigger function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_prod_price
BEFORE INSERT ON products
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_update_prod_price();
```

To *"drop the trigger"* (meaning the *trigger function*), you have to first drop all triggers referencing it and then drop the trigger function itself.

```
DROP TRIGGER update_prod_price ON products;
DROP FUNCTION trg_update_prod_price();
```

If you drop a table, all attached triggers are dropped with it. No need to drop those separately.

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this work? Creating a function and then executing the function for the trigger:

```
   def self.up 
     execute %q{
       create or replace function update_price() returns trigger as $$
         begin
           NEW.price := NEW.price + 5;
           return NEW;
         end;
       $$ language plpgsql }

      execute %{ create trigger trig1 before insert on products for each row execute function update_price()}
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

The [hair_trigger](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger) gem is a nice way to manage the creation of triggers.

Here is an example from hair_trigger's docs:

```
class AccountUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  trigger.after(:insert) do
    "UPDATE accounts SET user_count = user_count + 1 WHERE id = NEW.account_id;"
  end

  trigger.after(:update).of(:name) do
    "INSERT INTO user_changes(id, name) VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.name);"
  end
end
```